# Set timeout within hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have content that is dynamically loaded. This content needs to be invoked in the following way due to it's dynamic nature.

This works perfectly if no `setTimeout` is used. Is there a way of setting a timeout of 0.25 seconds in this instance?

[Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vuezt9dh/](https://jsfiddle.net/vuezt9dh/1/)

Works

```
$(".wrapper").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).find('.show-me').slideDown(150);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.show-me').slideUp(0);
  }
}, '.main-page');
```

Doesn't work

```
$(".wrapper").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.find('.show-me').slideDown(150);
    }, 250);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.show-me').slideUp(0);
  }
}, '.main-page');
```

Comment: What happens when you don't assign `$this` to `$(this)`?

Comment: What's the relevance between the dynamic elements and the timeout, it looks like it's just delaying the slideDown action, and you could just do `$this.find('.show-me').delay(250).slideDown(150);` for that ?

Comment: FWIW the code you say works doesn't do anything in your jsfiddle either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your targeting is incorrect, i'm suprised this works at all (didn't in my tests)

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/vuezt9dh/2/

Should be:

```
$(".main-page").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.find('.show-me').slideDown(150);
    }, 550);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.show-me').slideUp(0);
  }
}, '.wrapper');
```

Your `wrapper` and `main-page` were the wrong way around.

Comment: Ideally need to clear the timeout on `mouseleave`, otherwise a quick hover and out will result in it being displayed